Getting openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400: 'Extra inputs are not permitted' with an LLM model hosted on an on-prem GPU
I am not really able to find that much on this.
Here's some discussion on Github. I was following this tutorial. Is the issue that I can't use Mixtral with tool calling? Has anyone used Mixtral/some other local LLM models for Tool Calling? I am trying to figure out how to get this to work.
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
import httpx
import os
from langchain.chains.openai_functions import create_structured_output_runnable
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Annotated, Any, Dict, Optional, Sequence, TypedDict, List, Tuple


http_client = httpx.Client(verify=False)

llm = ChatOpenAI(
    base_url="<URL RUNNING MIXTRAL MODEL>",
    http_client=http_client,
    api_key="API KEY",
    model="mistral-7b-instruct-v02",
)
class Test(BaseModel):
    """Plan to follow in future"""

    Input: List[List] = Field(
        description="Input for Test cases to evaluate the provided code"
    )
    Output: List[List] = Field(
        description="Expected Output for Test cases to evaluate the provided code"
    )
    


test_gen_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    '''"Write unit tests for the provided code {code}.
'''
)
tester_agent = create_structured_output_runnable(
    Test, llm, test_gen_prompt
)
sample_code = """<SAMPLE JAVA Code Base>"""
tester_agent.invoke({"code":sample_code})

Detailed trace back
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'object': 'error', 'message': "[{'type': 'extra_forbidden', 'loc': ('body', 'function_call'), 'msg': 'Extra inputs are not permitted', 'input': {'name': '_OutputFormatter'}}, {'type': 'extra_forbidden', 'loc': ('body', 'functions'), 'msg': 'Extra inputs are not permitted', 'input': [{'name': '_OutputFormatter', 'description': 'Output formatter. Should always be used to format your response to the user.', 'parameters': {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'output': {'description': 'Plan to follow in future', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'Input': {'description': 'Input for Test cases to evaluate the provided code', 'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}, 'Output': {'description': 'Expected Output for Test cases to evaluate the provided code', 'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'array', 'items': {}}}}, 'required': ['Input', 'Output']}}, 'required': ['output']}}]}]", 'type': 'BadRequestError', 'param': None, 'code': 400}        

Just for more information, the server that serves completions is an OpenAI Compatible Server

According to the official docs on hugging face here v0.3 supports Tool/Function calling.

Got it. Will have to ask if my client can deploy this.
